# Combining JSONObject from multiple JSONArray into single JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, json, java-8

Am having 3 JSONArray like below.

RegionArray :

```
[  
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":620,
      "region_id":"en_US"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":40078,
      "region_id":"en_US"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":1048,
      "region_id":"en_US"
   }
]
```

CountryArray:

```
[  
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":620,
      "country_id":"DE"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":40078,
      "country_id":"DE"
   }
]
```

CompanyArray:

```
[
    {  
          "company_id":706,
          "catalog_product_id":40078
       },
       {  
          "company_id":706,
          "catalog_product_id":1048
       }
    }
]
```

These 3 different JSONArray am combining into single JSONArray and getting results like below. This array i have made by adding all the JSONObjects into single common array.`JSONArray.put(regionJSONObj);JSONArray.put(countryJSONObj);JSONArray.put(companyJSONObj);`

```
[  

    {  
      "catalog_product_id":620,
      "region_id":"en_US"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":40078,
      "region_id":"en_US"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":1048,
      "region_id":"en_US"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":620,
      "country_id":"DE"
   },
   {  
      "catalog_product_id":40078,
      "country_id":"DE"
   },
   {  
      "company_id":706,
      "catalog_product_id":40078
   },
   {  
      "company_id":706,
      "catalog_product_id":1048
   }

]
```

From all the 3 source JSONArray `catalog_product_id` key will be same in all the 3 JSONArray., so i want to build the destination JSONArray like below format.

```
[
    {
         "catalog_product_id":620,
         "region_id":"en_US",
         "country_id":"DE",
    },
    {
         "catalog_product_id":40078,
         "region_id":"en_US",
         "country_id":"DE",
         "company_id":706,
    },
    {
         "catalog_product_id":1048,
         "region_id":"en_US",
         "company_id":706

    }

]
```

All the 3 JSONArray `RegionArray`, `CountryArray` & `CompanyArray` having common key `catalog_product_id`. so i want to match `catalog_product_id` with all the 3 JSONArray and get the `region`, `country` & `company` information and build into an single Object for that particular `catalog_product_id`.

Comment: What code have you written so far to try and do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, JArray> map = 
jArrayLis.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(JArray::getCatalog_product_id, 
Function.identity()));
```

Comment: how can i print the results out of this.?

Comment: maybe you can use some json util,it provide function object to json and json to object. first you can use json to object ,then make object list to map,then,map to json string.  for example : print(JsonObject.toJsonString(map));